# Problem with jQuery selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following markup:

```
<table class="dogs">
    <tr>
        <td> <input class="name"> </td>
        etc.
```

I’m trying to select the `input` element using the following statement:

```
$('table.dogs > input.name')
```

However, I get no results.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe with that syntax you'd be looking for a direct child of `table`, when you should be looking for a direct child of `td`. Try:

```
$('table.dogs td > input.name')
```

You really don't need the `>` in that case though.

Comment: At that rate, `$('table.dogs input.name')` would work just as well.

Comment: Thanks! What is the > used for in jQuery?  Is it simply optional?

Comment: It means "direct child". So for example, if you had `<div class="test1"><span id="one"></span><div><span id="two"></span></div></div>`, `$('div.test1 > span')` would return only the `<span>` with `id="one"`, because the second `<span>` isn't a direct child. `$('div.test1 span')` would return both `<span>`s.

Answer (score 2):

Use this selector instead:

```
$('table.dogs input.name')
```

That way you're selecting all `input`s with class name `name`, which are descendants (rather than immediate children) of `table`s with class name `dogs`.

Answer (score 1):

[`jQuery('parent > child')`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent".

The `input.name` is not a direct child of `table.dogs`

you can use:

- `$('table.dogs td > input.name')`
- `$('table.dogs input.name')`

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the ">" $(“table.dogs input.name”)

Answer (score 0):

The proper selector in your case would be `table.docs > tbody > tr > td > input.name` as all tables rows are implicitely wrapped in TBODY unless TBODY/THEAD/TFOOT are specified manually.

Simple use the `table.docs input.name` selector to allow any elements between `table.docs` and `input.name`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use other selectors like this one.

```
$('table.dogs .name');
```

Child Selector (“parent > child”)
Selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent".